# Parse path as argument in python script

Tags: python

This is a part of python script `xyz.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from openpyxl import Workbook
import os
wb = Workbook()
path = "/home/Final_analysis/"
#print(os.listdir())
lis = os.listdir(path)
```

I wanted to use this script with different input files which are stored in different directories. For this script to run on multiple files I would have to change this part of the script every time.

```
path= "/home/Final_analysis/"
```

Can I parse the path as argument after python script for example

```
xyz.py path_to_my_file
```

in the command so that each time I don't have to change the script?

I tried running script as above after writing `sys.argv[1]` in path

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from openpyxl import Workbook
import os
wb = Workbook()
path = "sys.argv[1]"
#print(os.listdir())
lis = os.listdir(path)
```

and ran command `xyz.py /home/final_analysis`

but it still doesn't detect the path.
I am getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "combine_excel.py", line 8, in <module>
    lis = os.listdir(path)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sys.argv[1]'
```

I am using in python 2.7.6.

Comment: Did you mean `sys.argv[1]`? That should work. Does the path contain spaces?

Comment: Don't pass `sys.argv[1]` as a string, use it directly: `path = sys.argv[1]`. Don't forget to `import sys` before it, tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass `sys.argv[1]` as a string, use it directly: `path = sys.argv[1]`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from openpyxl import Workbook
import os
import sys
wb = Workbook()
path = sys.argv[1]
#print(os.listdir())
lis = os.listdir(path)
```

(per zwer's comment to the question.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what people have commented on you post,
you can also use the `"{}".format()` syntax.
A really clean way to insert string into an already formed string.